# How a Search Script like InoutScripts' Inout Spider attains scalability?

Tags: hadoop

I want to know more about how these Search Engines scripts like [InoutScripts'](http://www.inoutscripts.com/?index1) [Inout Spider](http://www.inoutscripts.com/products/inout_spider/?index1) attains scalability.

Is it because of the technology they are using. 
Do u think is it because of the technology of combining hadoop and hypertable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For storing and large scale processing of data sets on clusters of commodity hardware, Hadoop is used which is an open source software framework. Hadoop is an Apache top level project being built and used by a global community of contributors and users. At the application layer itself Hadoop detects and handle failures rather than rely on hardware to deliver high availability.